# Packet data needed fot the model

Tags: neural-network, dataset, data

I want to use this data set https://huggingface.co/datasets/rdpahalavan/network-packet-flow-header-payload for network attack classification

Here is packet structure from the README file.

[image]
Assuming I have successfully trained the model
I don't understand where i can find or how to craft such packet structure to use it in the real application.
My thought was it's a Wireshark packet bytes but i'm not sure

can someone please point me with what tools I can achieve such packet structure.